# CSS link in overlay taking over a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<div>` that contains a link.

At the bottom right corner of this `<div>`, I have an overlay element which takes over the whole `<div>` when hovered.

This overlay element also contains a link.

My problem is that the link in the overlying element is not clickable.

The problem is because I use `pointer-events: none;` on class `.overlay-content`, but if I don't use it, both links become dead.

Please see code here:

```css
.panel-default1 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap {
  display: block;
  background-color: #e8c63d;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  right: -320px;
  bottom: -320px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap:hover {
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(4);
}

.overlay-content {
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #333;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.overlay-content h2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 0 0 12px;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap:hover~.overlay-content {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default1">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <div class='amg-corner-button_wrap'></div>

    <div class="overlay-content">
      <h2>Image Ink Logo</h2>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- panel body -->

</div>
<!-- panel default -->
```

Also, [here is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2auh7gn/).

Is there any way that I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried adding "pointer-events: all" (or whatever the default is) directly to the link tag that you want to work?

Comment: If you do that, the hover effect disappears when you hover over the link.

Comment: I think some JavaScript might be in order.

Comment: Inspecting the elements, it looks like the reason you aren't able to click the links is because of the layering of divs one on top of the other. Have you tried moving from transitions to animations and using display none for the first 1% of the animation and then the rest of the 99% of the animation would be the transition you already have? It's a lot more management of animation but it would solve the layering issue eating the clicks.

Comment: You can probably do this without JavaScript if you remove the `pointer-events` property and use z-index, and use animations instead of transitions (you would need `animation-fill-mode: forwards` which doesn't have a transitions counterpart).

Comment: Eager to see your ideas in action :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't believe I actually found a pure CSS solution without any drawbacks.

```css
.panel-default1 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap {
  display: block;
  background-color: #e8c63d;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  right: -320px;
  bottom: -320px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.wrap:hover .amg-corner-button_wrap {
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(4);
}

.overlay-content {
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #333;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.overlay-content h2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 0 0 12px;
}

.wrap:hover .amg-corner-button_wrap ~ .overlay-content {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default1">
   <div class="panel-body">
     <a href="#">Link</a>
     <div class="wrap">
        <div class='amg-corner-button_wrap'></div>
        <div class="overlay-content">
          <h2>Image Ink Logo</h2>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- panel body -->
</div> <!-- panel default -->
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ff79jj4/1/)

Instead of listening to the `:hover` event on the corner-button, listen to it on a parent element. Since the `:hover` will be dispatched regardless of the mouse interaction of the elements' children, it is possible to set `pointer-events: auto` to the children containing links (overlay-content), once the corner-button has been hovered. Now, that the overlay-content is hoverable and since it's a child of the wrapping div, it will cause the `:hover` to stay active over the whole wrapping div.

Comment: Very, very nice Manuel. Thank you. But can you actually explain a little more what you did ?

Comment: @mattvent Ok, I've added an explanation. You can compare the css with your previous css and see what exactly has changed. It's only 3 lines + an additional div in the html.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using JS style swapping instead of CSS pointer events for this problem.  You need to trigger one change to your css when you mouse over the bottom corner, and a separate event when you mouse out of the container.  I do not believe CSS gives you that kind of conditional control.

Answer (score 0):

Here is half a solution using animations instead of transitions. This works for when you hover on to the amg-corner-button_wrap but not when you move off it. I'm a bit new to animations so hopefully someone here who knows more maybe able to help you with the second half.

There is also a weird visual in here if you hover on the amg-corner-button_wrap and hover off mid transition. The reason for this is that I added a background color to overlay-content so when it's fading in and you mouse off amg-corner-button_wrap the swipe starts to reverse before the fade is complete.

Anyway, hope this 50% solution helps you or others drive this to 100%! Have to run to a meeting, good luck :-)

```css
@keyframes example {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.panel-default1 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap {
  display: block;
  background-color: #e8c63d;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  right: -120px;
  bottom: -120px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.overlay-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #e8c63d;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #333;
  left: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.overlay-content h2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 0 0 12px;
}

.overlay-content~.amg-corner-button_wrap,
.amg-corner-button_wrap:hover {
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(4);
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap:hover~.overlay-content,
.overlay-content:hover {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default1">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <a href="#" onclick="alert('outer')">Link</a>

    <div class='amg-corner-button_wrap'></div>

    <div class="overlay-content">
      <h2>Image Ink Logo</h2>
      <a href="#" onclick="alert('inner')">Link</a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- panel body -->

</div>
<!-- panel default -->
```

Comment: This all said, if this were my code, I would probably try to figure out how to break up the overlay-content and amg-corner-button_wrap... but I can see why that's a bit difficult. Maybe instead of animating the corner object to get bigger, instead animate the background of overlay-content. Using keyframes will make this easier for you. the 1% -> 50% would be the background transition. The 50% -> 100% would be bringing in the text.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working fiddle for a css and html only change: https://jsfiddle.net/y2auh7gn/4/.

It separates the link from `overlay-content` and places it where it's supposed to be with `position: absolute`. We need to move the link out of `overlay-content` so that when we hover over it the overlay doesn't disappear.

There's a side-effect where the link pops out with the corner piece.